# how to break while read loop in bash

Tags: shell, scripting

I am trying below code to get input from user and print the array. But when I try to execute it, it asks for input and is not stopping. How to stop the while loop from user input and echo the array? I tried ctrl+c but that exits the script execution.

```
i=0
while read x; do
  a[i]=$x
done
echo "${a[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

you need a break condition to get out of your while loop. You can stop it with `break`
If you want a list with a pre-defined number of input, you must increment `((i++))` (However, a "for" loop may be better in these conditions)

```
i=0
echo "to stop type [exit]"
while read x
do
    if [[ $x == "exit" ]]
        then
            echo "out"  
            break
    fi
    a[i]=$x
    ((i++))
done
echo "${a[@]}"
```

If you want your user to type a specific word to stop and directly print the array you can bind a word with a "if" statement inside your while loop

```
echo "to stop type [exit]"
while read x
do
    if [[ $x == "exit" ]]
        then
            echo "out"  
            break
    fi
    a+=$x
done
echo "${a[@]}"
```